# how to optimize loading time of my website?

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp, magento-1.7

I am new to php developer and developed a website in magento 1.7.
My website take a too much time to loading.
I deleted caches , re indexing the date comprise images still take lot time for loading.
please suggest me how to optimize the loading time of my website.

thanks in advance .

Comment: I think there is no way to answer this question. Improving website performance requires that you find the bottle necks first. I think you better find these first, and if you have specific problems resolving those you could pose questions about these in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

### Enable Output Compression

This section will turn on the apache mod_deflate module, which compresses text, css, and javascript before it is sent to the browser. This results in a smaller download size. To enable, simply uncomment the appropriate lines so that it looks like the following:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript 

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>
```

- See more at: http://docs.nexcess.net/article/optimizing-magento-performance.html#sthash.ZUpf53Fy.dpuf

### Enable Expires Headers

NOTE: This does not work on Litespeed servers.
Browsers use Expires headers to determine how long a page component can be cached. Static components, like images, should have far-future expires headers, but truthfully, all page components should have expires headers. To turn this feature on, just uncomment the appropriate line and add "ExpiresActive On" right above it. See below:

#

### Add default Expires header

### http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
```

- See more at: http://docs.nexcess.net/article/optimizing-magento-performance.html#sthash.ZUpf53Fy.dpuf

**Reference taken from [here](http://docs.nexcess.net/article/optimizing-magento-performance.html)**

This has worked for me to a good extent.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at these results: http://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.fashiza.com/KLDZeYuI

It seems like you'd gain alot in this case **moving some of your javascript down** and checking if all of your images have:

**1)** defined width and height in css.

**2)** format optimised for the web

EDIT: You are loading almost 500kb of javascript. This is probably the main reason. Try to compress your js and decide if you really need that much.

Answer (score 0):

1.http://www.fashiza.com/media/js/1348d08285c79d6cda3eb91987e1942f.js
is too big 100KB
minimify that

2.http://www.fashiza.com/media/css/d2d005572b30b4d004b45f21ee567278.css
is too big

3.no file:productsliderpoint

google:compress js and you will find answer

i.stack.imgur.com/eh1NR.jpg

this is not normal

Answer (score 0):

Tips for Magento site speed up
Summary:

- Enable all Magento caching layers.
- Configure your web server to enable Connection Keep-Alive, enable mod_expire, gzip compression.
- Enable MySQL Query caching.
- Install APC or XCache to cache PHP opcode.
- Install Memcache and configure Magento to store session and cache to memory.
- Install third-party Full Page Cache Magento extension.
- Install Varnish cache server for full page caching on system layer.

You can check detailed instruction: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/36225/

Answer (score 0):

Create benchmarks to measure what causes the largest time lags. This helps you to narrow down the problem, thus, gain a better understanding, as your question is too broad to enable us to help you.